# excev() help: can I use "./program"?

Tags: c++, linux, exec

I have been trying to use excev to launch a program that I made. I need to say something like `execv("./myprogram");`. However, that does not work. I have tried `execv("myprogram");`.
Help anyone?

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Comment: It throws an error. In errno: it says that it doesn't exist or that the program doesnt have permission.

Comment: Which probably means that you are running your code in a different directory than you think. Try adding `cout << getcwd() << endl;` or something similar to show what your "current working directory" is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const char *path = "./myprogram";
const char *arg0 = path;

if (execl(path, arg0, (char *) NULL) == -1) {
    perror("execl");
}
```

Try that. The first argument is the program name, and rest are the command-line arguments. The first command-line argument is traditionally the name of the program (`$0` in a shell script). So you pass the program name twice, in effect. The end of the argument list is indicated with `(char *) NULL`.

If that doesn't work, make sure the current directory is correct.

Comment: only problem with arg passing

Comment: Not working... what did I do wrong?  = `execvp("./writer",(char* const*)"./writer"/*,(const char*)args*/);`. It was woking this morning.